# java memory settings amazon m3.xlarge

Tags: java, jenkins, jvm

The question is simple in my Jenkins that run slave machines to execute jobs with this kind of amazon machines, which java memory settings shall I put it?.
I´m executing a web service that gets a lot of memory.
The machine is 15gb of memory.

My current configuration is:

```
 -Xms1024m -Xmx4072m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you know the default settings need to be changed, I would leave the default settings.  If the `-Xmx` is not set, it will be 1/4 of main memory and 4 GB is not unreasonable.  You might like to reduce this if your builds are not that big, or increase it is they are really big.

BTW A 16 GB server is a tidy amount these days, and the size I use TeamCity but not what I would call XL. ;)

Comment: those machines are just for run integration test. Look my current configuration. What do you think?

Comment: @paul apart from the increased MaxPermSize which I imagine you need for building web application (I never set it myself) you might not need the others.  Note the default maximum memory size will 1/4 of memory which is about what you are setting it to.  The minimum doesn't matter for such a long running process.

Comment: But how the default setting is configure by default?. Shall I try removing everything?

Comment: @paul unless Jenkins have specific recommendations that you know of, I suspect you don't need to set anything.  Adding command line parameter which you are not sure are needed can do as much hard as good.

Comment: I´m going to try and see how good/bad the performance is. I guess the speed of my integration test will have some little impact. Let´s see the benchmark resut. Thanks

Comment: @paul your tests will be run in their own JVM and these might need to be tuned.  However, the memory setting for Jenkins is unlikely to matter.  How you tune you integration tests entirely depends on what they do, but I would start with no settings, watch the memory usage of tests running using jvisualvm and work from there.

Comment: Not really the jenkins job configuration I believe is apply to this slave machine. Is the Maven_OPTS configuration

Comment: @paul My view on maximum settings; it is the point at which you would rather the program die than use more of it e.g. memory. You are not going for an optimising parameter as much as you are going for an upper limit.